# Datetime includes 't' for time gives an Error in c# when inserting

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

My web api list contains a datetime field which includes the following format
`"2018-09-17T09:35:01.5842031 05:30"` but it should be `"2018-09-17 09:35"` however, Processtime is datetime Column and this column values automatically converts to "2018-09-17T09:35:01.5842031 05:30" though I send it as datetime field

How do I accomplish this task when inserting the value.

Insert query is like this

```
foreach (var item in talleyheaderlist)
{
    SQL = "insert into TalleySheetHeader (Processtime) values (@ProcessStartTime)";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessStartTime", item._TsStartTime );
    con.Open(); 
    com.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    con.Close(); 
}
```

and i use C# code to insert to SQL server 2014 DB

parameter Insertion

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessStartTime", item.ProcessStartTime);
```

I appreciate somebody's help...

Comment: DateTime doesn't have a format, are you sure it isn't a string?

Comment: What error it gives?

Comment: @SeM : Error was " String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. "

Comment: Are you trying to parse `string` date to `DataTime` before passing as sqlcommand parameter?

Comment: What is the column type of `Processtime`? Why aren't you passing it directly as a `DateTime` value?

Comment: You need to give us an [mcve] rather than parts.of the puzzle. You may want to [stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @Richardissimo : well, this error occurs when i Insert the value through the Web Api and data are sent to the web api through Winodows Phone.

Comment: Dai :  Processtime is datetime Column,because this column values automatically converts to "2018-09-17T09:35:01.5842031 05:30"  though i send as datetime field

Comment: @Udk please [edit] your question, rather than adding important information in comments. There are 3 comments you've made which have information which should be in the question. Then you can delete those comments.

Comment: @ Richardissimo : hope it is correct now, thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1):

*"my...list contains a datetime field which includes the Following format "2018-09-17T09:35:01.5842031 05:30""*

Let me stop you there. The quoted value is a string representation of a value. That string might have come from a `DateTime` or (given that 05:30 could be a TimeZone) a `DateTimeOffset`, but it isn't that type any more.

You need to [stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), because (as it explains on that page) when you do...

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Processtime", item._TsStartTime );
```

and

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TalleyProcessStartTime", _valstartedtiem);
```

*(both of which come from your answer to your question)* both variables are strings, but your SQL wants that parameter to be a datetime, so you're letting/forcing SQL to make that conversion for you.

So you either need to get the original value (before it became a string), or convert the string back to a DateTime, using [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse), probably using the overload with DateTimeStyles, using the RoundTripKind. Although [that ISO format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip) should have a plus or minus for the TimeZone; but it might work.

Now that you have a datetime, explicitly pass it as a SqlDbType.DateTime, as shown on the AddWithValue link article. Now you can remove the `convert(...,121)` from the Sql, since the parameter is now the correct type.

Bonus tips: `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are both `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to call Close as the implicit Dispose will call it when it exits the using block.

Comment: yes, i have made some mistakes, when Posting, thank you for the highlight, and i'll make sure this wont happen again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for every One's help. but i found the answer after a while.
basically ths datetime format is in ISO 8601 format in that case,  I had to convert it as follows,

```
foreach (var item in talleyheaderlist)
  {
 SQL = "insert into TalleySheetHeader (Processtime) values convert(char(22),@Processtime,121)"; SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(SQL, con); com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Processtime", item._TsStartTime );
con.Open(); 
com.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
con.Close(); 
}
```

and to seperately split the date & time to remove 't' and then re-join

```
  string[] Separate = item._TsStartTime.Split(' ');

                    string a = Separate[0];
                    string[] _dateTime = a.Split('T');
                    string _startdate = _dateTime[0];
                    string _starttime = _dateTime[1];
                    string _valstartedtiem = _startdate +' ' + _starttime;

                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TalleyProcessStartTime", _valstartedtiem);
```

however , there may be other easy Solutions but so far this worked for me. if there is any easy Solution Please do share.

Comment: The very first comment on the question asked whether you were working with a string and this clearly shows `_TsStartTime` is a string. And SeM's upvoted comment asked the same and remained unanswered; so we had no way of getting that from the question. Hopefully you can now see why people were asking the questions. P.S. The space after the @ meant I didn't get notified of your comment, I just came back by chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
string dateTime = "2018-09-17T09:35:01.5842031 0530";
var date = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateTime.Replace(' ','-'), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

More on how 'T' and 'z' works is here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169814.htm

Answer (score -2):

Please insert following logic in your global.asax.cs file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "your date format";
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    //ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
}
```

Comment: The OP didn't say they were using ASP.NET, and altering the current culture's culture will have massive side-effects elsewhere in the OP's application. This is a very bad solution to the problem.